# No such file or directory when using sed in combination with find?

Tags: sed

I am trying to run a script which corrects line breaks in all PHP files. This is how it looks like:

```
find . -type f -name \*.php -print -exec sed -i '' 's/\r//' {} \;
```

The errors I get for all files is:

```
./downloader/lib/Mage/Backup/Exception/SomeFile.php sed: can't read
s/\r//: No such file or directory
```

Whats the error in the script?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
find . -type f -name \*.php -print -exec sed -i 's/\r//' {} \;
```

The issue is sed is expecting `sed -i <substitution_pattern> <file>`. In your incantation, the `''` is interpreted as the substitution pattern, then the `'s/\r//'` is being interpreted as the file

Comment: And it does exactly the same?

Comment: It does what I believe you intended to do. If I run the exact incantation in my answer, I get:  `$ find . -type f -name \*.php -print -exec sed -i 's/\r//' {} \;
./something.php
`

Comment: If I run the incantation in your post, I get: `$ find . -type f -name \*.php -print -exec sed -i '' 's/\r//' {} \;
./something.php
sed: can't read s/\r//: No such file or directory
`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is on `-i`, it depends on the OS you use.

```sh
sed -i '' 's/\r//' {}
```

On macOS, `sed` expects the file extension to use for the backup file as a separate argument, following `-i`. An empty string, as you use, tells it to not create a backup file.

On Linux, `sed` expects the file extension to be joined together with `-i` in a single argument. For example, `-i.bak` to append `.bak` to the file name to generate the name of the backup file or `-i` to not create a backup file.

Since you get an error that says that the file `'s/\r//'` does not exist it means that you are using Linux and `''` is interpreted as the `sed` program.

Remove `''` and it should work:

```sh
sed -i 's/\r//' {}
```